# Quotient group, quotient space, and homogeneous space

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, quotient-spaces, quotient-group, homogeneous-spaces

What are the relations between:

1. Quotient group (such as a  group $G/N$),
2. quotient space, and
3. homogeneous space?

I suppose the quotient space and homogeneous space are two types of generalizations of quotient groups. But what are the similarities and differences on their properties?

- **Explicit examples to demonstrate** that

(1) some is one of the three kinds, but not the other two of the three kinds

(2) some is two of the three kinds, but not the other one of the three kinds

(3) some satisfies all three kinds

--- will be sufficient to claim an answer.

Comment: both quotient group and quotient space are formed by partitioning into equivalence classes

Comment: Do we have examples that are quotient space, but not homogeneous space?

Comment: Do we have examples that are homogeneous space, but not quotient space?

Comment: It might be useful to write down precise definitions of all three. There are several inequivalent notions of "quotient group" and "quotient space".

Comment: Do you already know what an "equivalence relation" is and what is the set of "equivalence classes"? How about "quotient topology"? If not, that would be the place to start.